# Vim, iconv+nr2char and iconv+"\x.."

Tags: vim, utf-8

```
echo strtrans(iconv(       "\x80", "utf-8", "utf-32"))
```

Outputs «??» and

```
echo strtrans(iconv(nr2char(0x80), "utf-8", "utf-32"))
```

outputs «<80>». Why?

```
(zyx:~) % LANG=C vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Feb 12 2010 07:37:05)
Included patches: 1-303                                          
Modified by Gentoo-7.2.303
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `nr2char(0x80)` results in `U+0080`, which is equal to `"\xc2\x80"`. And `"\x80"` is not a valid utf-8 string.